# Line 17:36: 'state' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here is my code and I cannot find where the problem is

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class Product extends Component{

state = {
    id: this.props.product.id,
    productName: this.props.product.productName,
    price: this.props.product.price,
}
render(){
    return<div className="col-lg-g">
        <div className="card m-2">
            <div className="card-body">
                <div className="text-muted"># {this.props.id}</div>
                <h5 className="p-5 border-top">{this.props.productName}</h5>
                <div>$ {this.props.price}</div>
                //{console.log(state)}
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
}
```

}

it shows  Line 17:36:  'state' is not defined  no-undef
whenever I run the code

Comment: You have an comma after `product.price` to remove

Comment: And in state you're using `this.props.product.id` but in the html you're only using `this.props.id` etc.

Comment: @KScandrett yes but i have used product.id too in html it shows same problem

Comment: @K Scandrett, the comma dangle is an ESLint rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle .

Comment: you cannot access `state` directly, you need to use `this.state`

Answer (score 2):

That's a class, when you write `state = ...`  , that's an instance property, hence you access it with `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

ok i did console.log(state) but i should have used console.log(this.state)